# Accessing words in a string

Tags: python, text-mining

I just want to know how to get two different words present in a string.

For Example: I have string `A` defined

```py
A="aaed gyh thn ujn"
```

Q: I want to know how to get the words `"aaed"` and `"thn"` only from the string `A`. I don't need other words

Note this is a part of text mining project which I am doing currently

Comment: `A.split()` for a list of words, select the indexes you want.

Comment: You don't say how to identify the words that you want to extract? By their content? By position? Something else?

Comment: I want only "aaed" and "thn" to be displayed as a list output. it is based on content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want search it by re.findall you can use the concept below!

```
>>> import re
>>> a="aaed gyh thn ujn"
>>> re.findall(r"aaed\Wgyh", a)
['aaed gyh']
```

hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Use split() to split the string and you can fetch it based on index.

```
>>> A="aaed gyh thn ujn"
>>> lst=A.split()
>>> lst
['aaed', 'gyh', 'thn', 'ujn']
>>> lst[0]
'aaed'
>>> lst[1]
'gyh'
>>> lst[2]
'thn'
>>> lst[3]
'ujn'
```

Comment: Thanks very much . But can I use re.findall() in some way to get the output?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to split the variable `A` by space using `A.split(" ")`

```
A="aaed gyh thn ujn"
b = A.split(" ")
```

and then accessing values by the index number

```
print(b[0], b[2])
aaed thn
```

hope it helps...

Comment: It seems we cannot use any kind of expression with re.findall(). I wanted if re.findall() can be used in some way using specal characters or metacharacters of python expressions

Comment: re.findall() by their content or the position? and also if you satisfied with the answer  please mark it as a solution.